# Angular 8.x routing with named outlets

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I try to configure routing in angular 8.x application, with lazy loading and named outlets. I have the next configuration:

**main-layout.html**

```
<header>
  <app-top-menu></app-top-menu>
</header>
<mat-sidenav-container autosize="true" id="app-main-layout">
  <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
    <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <router-outlet name="toolbar"></router-outlet>
  <div id="app-layout-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app-router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'databases',
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature-modules/database-search/database-search.module')
                              .then(m => m.DatabaseSearchModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

There is a lazy loaded module router:

**databases-search-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'index',
    component: DatabaseListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DatabaseListActionsMenuComponent,
        outlet: 'toolbar'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'mappings',
    component: MappingsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DatabaseListActionsMenuComponent,
        outlet: 'toolbar'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DatabaseSearchRoutingModule { }
```

The aim here is to load different toolbar for different views. So `/databases/index` should load DatabaseListComponent into 'main' router outlet and DatabaseListActionsMenuComponent into named 'toolbar' outlet.
However, it is not working.

The main router outlet is populated correctly but the named outlet isn't. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What is the right configuration for this case?

Comment: `loadChildren: () => import('./feature-modules/database-search/database-search.module')
                              .then(m => m.DatabaseSearchModule)` You can't do that. You can't put functions in the router.

Comment: @mwilson based on angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Well, that's interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to put the primary outlet routes, and the `toolbar` outlet routes at the same depth, and have a componentless parent route for both, like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
        path: 'index',
        children: [{
                path: '',
                component: DatabaseListComponent
            }, {
                path: '',
                component: DatabaseListActionsMenuComponent,
                outlet: 'toolbar'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        path: 'mappings',
        children: [{
                path: '',
                component: MappingsComponent
            }, {
                path: '',
                component: DatabaseListActionsMenuComponent,
                outlet: 'toolbar'
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DatabaseSearchRoutingModule {}
```